# The 'controlType' attribute must be specified on the 'adapter' tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, inappbrowser

I want to store view state data in server side .

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter ControlType="System.Web.UI.Page" adapterType="ServerSideViewStateAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
```

while compiling solution im getting below error

The '`controlType`' attribute must be specified on the '`adapter`' tag.

I'm unable to use `System.Web.UI.Page` namespace in `visual studio 2008`

Comment: Is it a typo? Small 'c' in ControlType attribute?

Comment: actually my intellisence is not working . so i manually typed . do u know its c or C? @PiyushParashar

Comment: It should be 'c' I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo I guess. Change the attribute name from `ControlType` to `controlType`. It should be small `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensured the adapterType attribute matches the class namespace that was created for ViewStateAdapter.

```
<controlAdapters>
  <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.Page" adapterType="ServerSideViewStateAdapter" />
</controlAdapters
```

Answer (score 0):

To mantain view state in server side 
create one class file in app_code

```
using System.Web.UI.Adapters;
 public class ServerSideViewStateAdapter:PageAdapter
    {
        public override PageStatePersister GetStatePersister()
        {
           // return base.GetStatePersister();
            return new SessionPageStatePersister(this.Page);
        }

    }
```

and add browser folder - in browser folder add browser file- e.g"ViewStateAdapter" and add this code in that file

```
 <browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.Page" adapterType="ServerSideViewStateAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
    </browsers>
```